# Where can I find the details of pytest hook spec (for e.g., pytest_addoption) - supported parameters, default values, etc.?

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to use some pytest hooks, for e.g., pytest_addoption.
Where can I find the details of the hooks?

For e.g., pytest_addoption takes a parameter action.
action='store' is a possible value (as seen in some example).

Is there a document explaining the hooks in details?
I've checked this: http://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.3/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Sharad

Comment: Would this help? https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example

Comment: @sashk This doesn't help much. But thanks anyway :) I found the following source code URLS that has some more details on addoption and parser: https://pytest.org/latest/_modules/_pytest/config.html https://pytest.org/latest/_modules/

Answer (score 1):

The [writing plugins](http://pytest.org/latest/writing_plugins.html#pytest-hook-reference) page documents all available hooks.